# Applescript: new terminal window with theme pro

Tags: macos

I want to create a script which opens me a new terminal window with the theme pro. how would that script look like? I just managed to get a new window but I want to specify the theme.

I created a automator service for that, cause I want to use shortcuts.

I would need a propertie for the theme or get the infos out of it, somehow for rebuilding it.

---

So that works fine:

Set mode to `{"Basic", "Grass", "Novel", "Ocean", "Pro", "Red Sands"}`
set I to random number from 1 to 6

Set theme to item I of mode

But how can I get the current theme?  And does the script loos all its vars after its finished or does it somehow save it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do:

```
tell application "Terminal" to set current settings of (do script) to settings set "Pro"
```

Not sure, what you mean by this, though:

> i would need a propertie for the theme or get the infos out of it, somehow for rebuilding it.

Answer (score 2):

I wrote this applescript so that I could easily set the theme of the current window.  It allows me to set to a specific theme, a random one among a blessed set, or randomly among all available.

I uses aliases setup in my .bashrc to easily invoke this from the command line.  Examples are in the header.

```
-- StyleTerm.scpt
-- Sets theme of current terminal window/tab

-----------------------
-- Arguments
-----------------------
-- If a theme name is provided on the command line then set to that
-- Example
--   osascript StyleTerm.scpt Grass
--  
-- If multiple theme names are provided on command line then choose randomly among those
--    This allows for random behavior from within blessed set
-- Example
--   osascript StyleTerm.scpt Grass Basic Ocean "Red Sands"
--  
-- If no command line args are provided then choose randomly among all themes
-- Example
--   osascript StyleTerm.scpt
-----------------------

-----------------------
-- This is best utilized via aliases set up in shell config file
-- Examples from my .bashrc
--   # Theme specific aliases
--   alias grass='osascript ~/sbin/StyleTerm.scpt Grass'
--   alias basic='osascript ~/sbin/StyleTerm.scpt Basic'
--   # Random from blessed themes
--   alias btheme='osascript ~/sbin/StyleTerm.scpt Grass Basic Ocean "Red Sands"'
--   # Random themes
--   alias rtheme='osascript ~/sbin/StyleTerm.scpt'
-----------------------

on run argv
    tell application "Terminal"
        if (count argv) is 0 then
            -- Use random theme from all possible themes
            set newTheme to some settings set
            set current settings of selected tab of front window to newTheme
        else
            -- Use random theme from arguments 
            set newThemeName to some item argv
            set current settings of selected tab of front window to first settings set whose name is newThemeName
        end if
    end tell
end run
```

Comment: Here's the above in a Github gist. I had an issue running the above, but the gist worked perfectly. https://gist.github.com/khansensf/1714326 Thanks!